# adding database item to a php form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

am new to php and mysql and i would like some help on how to transfer data from a database field to a php form.i have displayed the data on a table and on the last column i have a button(sponsor) where you can select that row and a particular field will be displayed on a form that opens once you select the button(sponsor).i have three scripts where the data is displayed (needy.php),where the buttons sends the id/No field selected (add.php) and there form where the data is to be sent (details.php) below is the code.please help on how to go about it.

```
      needy.php

<?php

$username = "egesachi_baby";
$password = "babyclass" ;
$database = "egesachi_babyclass";
$server = "localhost";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);

$db_found = mysql_select_db($database)or die ("cannot connect");


if ($db_found) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM needy";
$result= mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>

<th>Photo</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>";

while($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>" . '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . 
base64_encode(     $db_field['Photo'])  .   
'"      width="280" height="280" />'; "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $db_field['Name']."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $db_field['Age']."</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<form action='add.php' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='pupilno' value='".$db_field['No']."'>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='sponsor' />";
echo "</form>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";  

}
echo "</table>";
 mysql_close($db_handle);

}


else {
   print "database not found";

 mysql_close($db_handle);
}

?>

 add.php

 <?php
     session_start();

   $username = "egesachi_baby";
   $password = "babyclass" ;
   $database = "egesachi_babyclass";
   $server = "localhost";

  $db_handle = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);

  $db_found = mysql_select_db($database)or die ("cannot connect");


if ($db_found) {

 if(isset($_POST['sponsor'])) {
   $id = $_POST['pupilno'];

     $sql = "SELECT Name FROM needy WHERE No= '$_POST['pupilno']'";
     $result= mysql_query($sql);

 while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

          $sponsored = $db_field['Name'] . "<BR>";


 }
mysql_close($db_handle);

 }

 else {

  print "Database NOT Found ";
  mysql_close($db_handle);

  }




 }


?> 

 details.php

 <html>
 <body>

      <form action="paypal.php" method="post">

      Pupil No:   <input type="text" name="pupilid"><p/>

      pupil Name: <input type="text" name="sponsored"><p/>

      Your Name:  <input type="text" name="name"><p/>

      Your Email :<input type="text" name="email"><p/>

      Phone No:   <input type="text" name="phone"><p/r>

      Country:    <input type="text" name="country"><p/>

      Contribution:<input type="text" name="con"><p/>



    <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're new to PHP, please don't start by writing 1990s style PHP.  For this sort of thing, [use a development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/). They'll give you much better examples to work from, provide all kinds of community add-ons, and will generally make it easier to be productive and get your application working. Seeing `mysql_query` in new code is not good, so I can only suppose you're working from a wildly out of date reference.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
add.php

...
 while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

          $sponsored = $db_field['Name'];


 }
header('Location: add.php?pupil='.$_POST['pupilno'].'&name='.$sponsored );
...
```

and then

```
details.php

...
  <form action="paypal.php" method="post">

  Pupil No:   <input type="text" name="pupilid" value="<?php $_GET['pupil'] ?>"><p/>

  pupil Name: <input type="text" name="sponsored" value="<?php $_GET['name'] ?>"><p/>

  Your Name:  <input type="text" name="name"><p/>

  Your Email :<input type="text" name="email"><p/>

  Phone No:   <input type="text" name="phone"><p/r>

  Country:    <input type="text" name="country"><p/>

  Contribution:<input type="text" name="con"><p/>



<input type="submit" value="Send it!">
</form>
...
```

HOWEVER, there is much more that should be done to validate the POST/GET variables and to protect yourself from SQL injection on you add.php page - I would combine the add.php and details.php scripts but that is based on the simplistic view of your example and there may be other reasons for having them seperated.

the php mysql function has also been deprecated (http://www.php.net/mysql_query) look into updating your scripts now to mysqli_query or PDO and read up on SQL injection prevention: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)